# How do I do a nxdomain check?

Tags: linux, unix, whois, command

my friend says this, but it doesn't work as it says "dig command not found"

```
dig ns <domain>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try to use

```
host -t ns <domain>
```

or

```
nslookup -type=ns <domain>
```

maybe one of these commands is already installed on your system

Answer (score 1):

You need to install bind-utils

```
yum install bind-utils
```

Comment: . . . and if he's running Windows? (All the world is *not* a Linux box)

Comment: The tags identify Linux, albeit not the distribution.

Comment: And do all distributions (out of the box) support yum? There's also a unix tag, which again kills the notion of yum as a valid answer.